# How to create a custom gallery having images of a particular folder on SD card?

Tags: android, gallery, thumbnails

I have seen the API demos of android (/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Gallery1.java) , but they take images from the res folder within the project. I want to create a gallery of the images which are put up in the folder: **/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures/**

All i could come up was this code, which, i suppose, displays all images.

```
public class ExistingPicGallery extends Activity {

private Cursor cursor;
private int columnIndex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery1);
    Gallery g=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID, 
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND};
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND +
            "="  + // Select only mini's 
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND; 
    cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, 
            selection,
            null,
            null);
    // Get the column index of the image ID
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(ExistingPicGallery.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}



 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     int mGalleryItemBackground;

      public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;

            TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.ExistingPicGallery);
            mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.ExistingPicGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return cursor.getCount();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(context);
            // Move cursor to current position
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get the current value for the requested column
            int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            // obtain the image URI
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Integer.toString(imageID) );
            String url = uri.toString();
            // Set the content of the image based on the image URI
            int originalImageId = Integer.parseInt(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length()));
            Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),
                            originalImageId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
            i.setImageBitmap(b);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            i.setBackgroundResource(0);
            return i;
        }

        private Context context;


        ;
    }
}
```

I have spent a lot of time looking for its solution, but no success..

Comment: Which is the problem with this code? Any error/exception thrown?

Comment: What is the problem with the code? What do you need help with?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22:there is no problem with this code, it is perfectly running. But i want the code that take the images which are put up in the folder: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures/
and displays in custom gallery.. thanks in advance

Comment: @DimitrisMakris there is  no exception, just this is not the code i am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made following changes in /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Gallery1.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return allFiles.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        if (convertView != null)
            myImageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        else {
            myImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            myImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(60, 60));
            myImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
            myImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        }

        Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(folder + "/"
                + allFiles[position]);
        BitmapDrawable drawableImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);
        myImageView.setImageDrawable(drawableImage);

        return myImageView;

    }

    private Context mContext;

    File folder = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath()+"/files/Pictures/");
            String[] allFiles = folder.list();


}
```

Hence, we get array of image names in this folder. In the sample, we got the array of IDs of the drawables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code i manage to come up with for you that uses a Cursor to fetch the images on the SDCard...

```
/**
* Displays images from an SD card.
*/
 public class SDCardImagesActivity extends Activity {

/**
 * Cursor used to access the results from querying for images on the SD card.
 */
private Cursor cursor;
/*
 * Column index for the Thumbnails Image IDs.
 */
private int columnIndex;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sdcard);

    // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

    GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
    sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    // Set up a click listener
    sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Get the data location of the image
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // Return all rows
                    null,
                    null);
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get image filename
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            // Use this path to do further processing, i.e. full screen display
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Adapter for our image files.
 */
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
        context = localContext;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView picturesView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            picturesView = new ImageView(context);
            // Move cursor to current position
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get the current value for the requested column
            int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
            picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
            picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        }
        else {
            picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }
        return picturesView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sir, how do i get this "pathName" for all the images in the folder /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures/ ??

Comment: Check out my edit. Make sure you read through and see how i have constructed the code.

Comment: Sir, I guess that i have to write something in the 3rd parameter of managedQuery() like :
    

cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,          projection, 
            **imgpath** +" LIKE '/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures/%'",
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);  

If this is what should be done, then what should be the expression for **imgpath** ?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi below link given more details Custom Gallery
http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/02/multiple-choose-custom-gallery.html